# Reset linked select drop down field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on the following code to give my site a "linked" select drop down field. Everything seems to be working well except when I unselect the first option "country" to "select a country" the follow two options don't reset + hide themselves. What code do I need to achieve those? Thank you for advice!

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
    $(function() {
        $("#select1").change(function() {
            if ($(this).data('options') == undefined) {
                $(this).data('options', $('#select2 option').clone());
            }
            var id = $(this).val();
            var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[data-value=' + id + ']');
            $('#select2').html(options).show();
        });

        $("#select2").change(function() {
            if ($(this).data('options') == undefined) {
                $(this).data('options', $('#select3 option').clone());
            }
            var id = $(this).val();
            var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[data-value=' + id + ']');
            $('#select3').html(options).show();
        });
    }); 
</script>
            
<select name="select1" id="select1">
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
    <option value="india">India</option>
    <option value="america">America</option>
</select>


<select name="select2" id="select2" style="display: none;">
    <option value="">Select State</option>
    <option data-value="india" value="orissa">Orissa</option>
    <option data-value="india" value="telangan">Telangan</option>
    <option data-value="america" value="usa">USA</option>
    <option data-value="america" value="america">California</option>
</select>

<select name="select3" id="select3" style="display: none;">
    <option value="">Select city</option>
    <option data-value="orissa">Nal</option>
    <option data-value="orissa">Mir</option>
    <option data-value="telangan">Hyd</option>
    <option data-value="telangan">Vija</option>
    <option data-value="usa">ttt</option>
    <option data-value="usa">ttt</option>
    <option data-value="america">KRK</option>
    <option data-value="america">MRK</option>
</select>
```

Try using refresh page.

Comment: keeping your current strategy untouched, I think you should just have an if condition before setting the `options` variable. If the `id == ""` just hide the next select elements and return. Do that in each dropdown change event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a check on the selected value in select1 if 'select country' option is selected hide the other two selects:

```js
$(function(){
  $("#select1").change(function() {
    if ($(this).data('options') == undefined) {
      $(this).data('options', $('#select2 option').clone());
    }
    var id = $(this).val();
    if(id == '') {
      $('#select2').hide();
      $('#select3').hide();
    } else {
      var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[data-value=' + id + ']');
                                              $('#select2').html(options).show();
    }
});
                                    
                                    
  $("#select2").change(function() {
    if ($(this).data('options') == undefined) {
      $(this).data('options', $('#select3 option').clone());
    }
    var id = $(this).val();
    var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[data-value=' + id + ']');
    $('#select3').html(options).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select1" id="select1">
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
    <option value="india">India</option>
    <option value="america">America</option>
</select>


<select name="select2" id="select2" style="display: none;">
    <option value="">Select State</option>
    <option data-value="india" value="orissa">Orissa</option>
    <option data-value="india" value="telangan">Telangan</option>
    <option data-value="america" value="usa">USA</option>
    <option data-value="america" value="america">California</option>
</select>

<select name="select3" id="select3" style="display: none;">
    <option value="">Select city</option>
    <option data-value="orissa">Nal</option>
    <option data-value="orissa">Mir</option>
    <option data-value="telangan">Hyd</option>
    <option data-value="telangan">Vija</option>
    <option data-value="usa">ttt</option>
    <option data-value="usa">ttt</option>
    <option data-value="america">KRK</option>
    <option data-value="america">MRK</option>
</select>
```